# Is there a way to install a fully updated Raspbian directly from SD card (without needing to update when pi first boots)

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-stretch

I'm working with a few Pi zeros and I'd rather not go out to buy accessories to connect them all to the internet but I want to update them to the newest version of Raspbian.

Is there any way to load a fully up to date version of Raspbian directly on the SD card from the get go, so that I don't need to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` on first boot for all of the Pis?

Comment: do it once, create an image from that SD card to use when creating new SD cards?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm a bit of a noob so humour me for a second. If I'm understanding correctly, I install Raspbian normally once on say an RPI3 with internet. Update it. Then take out the SD card, put it back into my Mac/PC, and then somehow convert that back into an image again? Any chance you know the steps to convert it back to an image from the SD card?

Comment: how do you write the SD card? I've added an answer anyway, see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd go about it

1. write image to SD card that is exactly the same size or smaller than your target SD cards
2. boot this card in a pi
3. update/upgrade, and perform any other customisations you want/need
4. shutdown gracefully
5. add `init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh` at the end of the first line in `cmdline.txt` (if you used a smaller SD card in step 1
6. create your new image from this SD card

Step 6 depends on your computer ... how do you do step 1? Does this process/program have a read image instead of write image function (win32disk image does)

if you use `dd` it's simple

to write, it's something like

```
dd if=raspbian.img of=/dev/someDeviceHere [other options]
```

to create an image, simply swap if/of

```
dd of=myraspbian.img if=/dev/someDeviceHere  [other options]
```

where `[other options]` are whatever else you use on the command line

Comment: I'm using the `dd` command on Mac to copy the Raspbian stretch image to an 8gig micro SD card

Comment: I've updated the answer ... if your SD cards are all identical in size, then you can skip step 5

Comment: Very helpful thank you @Jaromanda X. One last question for you. If I edit settings on my RPI between steps 3 and 4 (i.e. resolution settings in `raspi-config`) will those be saved when I copy over the new image so I don't need to change those settings later?

Comment: yes, of course - do as much customisation as you want between steps 3 and 4

Comment: Awesome, thanks for breaking it down step by step for me! Cheers

Comment: Also if I'm only using 8gig SD cards I can skip step 5, correct?

Comment: As long as target cards are at least the same size. 8gb brand one may be not exactly the same as brand two

Comment: @Matt If you use a 4 GB (8 GB) SD Card for customizing and a 8 GB (16 GB) SD Card for your RPi0 then you are on the save side with the size of your cards (said in step 1). But then you have always to use step 5.